# Tkinter - Retrieve Values from Dynamically Generated Widgets - Callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to make a GUI through Tkinter that will calculate production based on some user input. Based on the number of systems the user selects, I have that number of option menus pop up for the inverter type and that number of entry widgets pop up for modules per string, strings per inverter, and inverters per system. See the picture for an example if the user selects 2 systems.

I'm using a callback function to grab the user selected number of systems real time to dynamically generate the inverter/module widgets discussed above.

My issue is that I'm unable to retrieve the values from these widgets. My attempt is shown in the weather calculation function.

I'm assuming the issue is because I generate the widgets/variables within the callback function. However, I haven't been able to figure out a way to dynamically generate the number of widgets based on user input outside of the callback function.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated!

```
  class Window:  

# Define User Inputs:  
    def __init__(self, master):  
        master.title('Production Analysis Tool')  

 # EQUIPMENT PARAMETERS         

    # callback function to create entry boxes based on number of systems  
        def callback(*args):  
            self.system_size = int(self.system_size_raw.get())  

        # Modules per String  
            self.L3 = Label(root, text = "Number of Modules Per String").grid(row=20, column=1, sticky=E)  
            self.modules_string_raw = IntVar(root)  
            modules_per_string =[]  
            for i in range(self.system_size):  
                self.label = Label(root, text = "System {}".format(i+1)).grid(row=21+i, column=1, sticky=E)  
                self.widget = Entry(root).grid(row=21+i, column=2, sticky=W)  
                modules_per_string.append(self.widget)  

    # Number of Systems  
        self.L1 = Label(root, text = "Number of Systems").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E)  
        self.system_size_raw = IntVar(root)  
        choices = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]  
        self.popupMenu2 = OptionMenu(root, self.system_size_raw, *choices).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)  
        self.system_size_raw.trace("w", callback)  


#Calculation Function  

    def weather_calculation(self):     

    # Get Values from User Input  

        self.mod_strings = np.float(self.modules_string_raw.get())  

root = Tk()  
root.configure()  
window = Window(root)  
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Example GUI]

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please try to condense this down to a [mcve]. If the problem is with getting values from a dynamic set of entries, all we need is a way to set the number, a function that generates them, and the function that gets the values. We don't need the code to process a csv file, you can just use some static data.

Comment: I've condensed it to just show part of the callback function, where I call the callback function, and my attempt at retrieving the values.

Comment: When I run the code and select "3" from the dropdown, it only creates a single label before throwing an error.

Comment: Sorry, I still had references to files there. I've changed it to just the modules per string input. This should work for you now

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is save a reference to your `Entry` widgets in a list. You can then iterate over that list to get the value of each widget.

It appears that you're already saving the widgets to the list variable `modules_per_string`. All you need to do is make that global or an object attribute rather than a local variable so other functions can reference it.

Comment: So I thought I was doing that with "modules_per_string = [ ]" but does this have to be outside the function?

Comment: There's nothing special you have to do for tkinter -- just normal python scoping rules. If you need to access the list from more than one place, it needs to be global or in some other form that both places can access (eg: an object attribute).

Comment: I've successfully stored and retrieved user input values from widgets outside of this callback function. However, I still can't figure out how to store and access the entries in the callback function. Could you provide an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As Bryan Oakley said, make list for widgets to store each objects of entries and label in two list.

For Example:

```
import tkinter as tk
class Demo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("600x600")
        systems_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="No Of Systems:")
        systems_label.place(x=100, y=20)

        no_Of_System_Ent = tk.Entry(self.root, width=15)
        no_Of_System_Ent.place(x=200, y=20)

        submit_Button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Submit", command=lambda: self.process(no_Of_System_Ent.get()))
        submit_Button.place(x=350,y=20)

    def display(self,sys_len): 
        for i in range(sys_len):
              buffer = self.obj_of_entries[i].get()
              print(buffer)

    def delete(self,sys_len):
         for i in range(sys_len):
              self.obj_of_entries[i].destroy()
              self.obj_of_labels[i].destroy()

    def process(self,length_sys):
         self.obj_of_entries = []
         self.obj_of_labels = []
         y_pos = 80
         for i in range(int(length_sys)):
              #Adding objects of label in list 'obj_of_labels'
              self.obj_of_labels.append(tk.Label(self.root,text="System "+str(i)))
              self.obj_of_labels[len(self.obj_of_labels)-1].place(x=100,y=y_pos)

              #Adding objects of entry in list 'obj_of_entries'
              self.obj_of_entries.append(tk.Entry(self.root,width=15))
              self.obj_of_entries[len(self.obj_of_entries)-1].place(x=200,y=y_pos)

              #Increments Y by 50
              y_pos = y_pos + 50

              self.delete_Button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Delete All", command=lambda: self.delete(int(length_sys)))
              self.delete_Button.place(x=200,y=400)

              self.print_Button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Print All", command=lambda: self.display(int(length_sys)))
              self.print_Button.place(x=350,y=400) 

ob=Demo()
```

In this example:

I created a entry and button in the init function to take no of systems from user.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.root.geometry("600x600")

    systems_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="No Of Systems:")
    systems_label.place(x=100, y=20)

    no_Of_System_Ent = tk.Entry(self.root, width=15)
    no_Of_System_Ent.place(x=200, y=20)

    submit_Button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Submit", command=lambda: self.process(no_Of_System_Ent.get()))
    submit_Button.place(x=350,y=20)
```

After clicking submit button,it will go to process function.

Ps: length_sys is the no of systems.

```
def process(self,length_sys):
    self.obj_of_entries = []
    self.obj_of_labels = []
    y_pos = 80
    for i in range(int(length_sys)):
        #Adding objects of label in list 'obj_of_labels'
        self.obj_of_labels.append(tk.Label(self.root,text="System "+str(i)))
        self.obj_of_labels[len(self.obj_of_labels)-1].place(x=100,y=y_pos)

        #Adding objects of entry in list 'obj_of_entries'
        self.obj_of_entries.append(tk.Entry(self.root,width=15))
        self.obj_of_entries[len(self.obj_of_entries)-1].place(x=200,y=y_pos)

        #Increments Y by 50
        y_pos = y_pos + 50

        self.delete_Button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Delete All", command=lambda: self.delete(int(length_sys)))
        self.delete_Button.place(x=200,y=400)
```

It will append the entry and label obj in its respective list and place the current obj in GUI window.
At Last,It will increment y axis by 80 so that next label and entry comes down to  the previous one.

If user clicks delete all button,then it will go to delete all list obj of both entries and labels.

Ps: sys_len is the no of systems.

```
def delete(self,sys_len):
    for i in range(sys_len):
        self.obj_of_entries[i].destroy()
        self.obj_of_labels[i].destroy()
```

To see the content,use this code:

(It will print in the Python shell so you can see if data is correct or not.)

```
def display(self,sys_len): 
    for i in range(sys_len):
        buffer = self.obj_of_entries[i].get()
        print(buffer)
```

I think I solved the doubt.
Ciao!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried this and I'm still not able to store the values the user inputs. Any suggestions?

Comment: I changed my answer in which I added about your doubt.